# Como verificar se existe algum banco de dados sqlite na aplicação?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlite3, banco-de-dados

Estou com o seguinte dilema:

Estou montando um app onde realizo uma sincronização entre um banco de dados MySqle o SQLite utilizando um Webservice.

Meu banco de dados já está disponível no MySql, e no meu app durante minha tela splash preciso fazer uma verificação: Se existir algum banco de dados já sincronizado no sistema o usuário é redirecionado para a tela de login. Se não, ele deve ser redirecionado para a tela onde ele deve informar os dados para realizar a sincronização.

Se fosse uma verificação em uma tabela eu teria que informar o nome do banco de dados para meu SQLiteOpenHelper e assim realizar a operação em determinada tabela, mas como faço isso no banco de dados em sí?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode verificar passando o nome específico de um banco de dados. Algo assim:

```
public static boolean doesDatabaseExist(ContextWrapper context, String dbName) {
    File dbFile = context.getDatabasePath(dbName);
    return dbFile.exists();
}
```

***EDIT:***

*Complementando como sugerido:*

Se no Android você nunca tiver chamado o método onde cria a tabela (e portanto o arquivo) esse método vai retornar false (pois ainda não existe esse BD), do contrário ele retornará true.

Ele também pode estar em qualquer classe. Em meus projetos ele costuma ficar em uma classe DbHelper ou DbUtils, junto com outros métodos utilitários de banco de dados.

Comment: Mas isso verifica se o banco de dados(arquivo .sqlite) existe? Tipo, se a aplicação está iniciando pela primeira vez?

Comment: Se você nunca tiver chamado o método onde cria a tabela (e portanto o arquivo) esse método vai retornar false (pois ainda não existe esse BD), do contrário ele retornará true.

Comment: A melhor solução seria mostrar a tela de login com uma opção abaixo escrito cadastra-se.

Comment: Então esse método deve ser adicionado a classe auxiliar do banco(a que extende SQLiteOpenHelper) certo? P.S.: não fui eu quem perguntou, só curiosidade mesmo hehe

Comment: Sim, apenas depois que eu vi que não era o mesmo da pergunta. Haha. Esse método pode estar em qualquer classe. Em meus projetos ele costuma ficar em uma classe DbHelper ou DbUtils, junto com outros métodos utilitários de banco de dados.

Comment: +1 pelo esclarecimento. Só uma dica, seria interessante você adicionar esses esclarecimentos na resposta também, assim ela fica ainda mais clara e completa, e mais passivel de ser positivada pelos outros colegas :)

Comment: Ok, obg. Feito! :)

Comment: Ótima resposta Luiz, porém no meu caso não vai dar certo. Deixe me explicar: No meu caso, o nome de cada banco de dados seria definido por um token diferente relacionado a cada empresa cadastrada no app, então antes de realizar uma primeira sincronização eu não teria como informar o nome do banco de dados para utilizar com o seu método, mas mesmo assim muito obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Decidi criar um banco de dados padrão contendo o nome e id do usuário, sempre que o aplicativo é aberto verifico neste banco de dados, se ele estiver povoado -> Tela de login, se não -> Tela de Sincronização, onde o usuário informa seus dados, após a sincronização o banco de dados padrão recebe o nome e id, e um novo banco de dados com o token do usuário é criado.